# Port translation and websphere application

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, port, web-application, translation

I have a java application running in Websphere Application Server (WAS) on port 80 (using IBM HttP server, IHS). Now I need port 80 for other purposes on my external ip. I just setup port translation to redirect port 85 to port 80.

Now when I enter my:  http://my_public_ip:85 I see the index page of IHS. But whenever I try to browse to http://my_public_ip:85/application_name I get the following error:

> Not found The requested url ... on this server
>
> IBM_HTTP_SERVER at
>   my_public_ip port 85

from inside my network it works fine I can just enter: http://my_internal_network_ip/application_name and it works.

Should I add an application mapping and were/how do I do that?

Or

Should I add a virtual host (in IHS or WAS)?

Comment: is `application_name` a dynamic app?  can you try if  `http://my_public_ip:85/static/file/a.html` works?

Comment: it's a java application, not html

Comment: i mean if you create a folder and an html file within and you can access it, probably your java application need other ports/firewall tweaks to make it serve publicly

Comment: ok, I will test it out later